# How to insert list of data.frame(s) to database?

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I want to make an SQLite database from a list of data.frame(s) using the dplyr package. It looks like `dplyr::copy_to` is what I need. I think the problem is related to [NSE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). Also see the vignette on [dplyr with databases](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html).

```
data(iris)
data(cars)

res <- list("iris" = iris, "cars" = cars)

my_db <- dplyr::src_sqlite(paste0(tempdir(), "/foobar.sqlite3"),
                       create = TRUE)

lapply(res, function(x) dplyr::copy_to(my_db, x))
```

> Error: Table x already exists.

Comment: Try deleting and re-creating your `sqlite` database. It looks like it already worked successfully.

Comment: Still fails. There is no Table x. Only iris and cars. That is why I think it is a NSE issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because the default table name is based off of the name of the data frame in R. When using `lapply`, it does **not** take the index name.

The documentation for `dplyr::copy_to.src_sql` contains:

```
## S3 method for class 'src_sql'
copy_to(dest, df, name = deparse(substitute(df)),
  types = NULL, temporary = TRUE, unique_indexes = NULL, indexes = NULL,
  analyze = TRUE, ...)
```

The line `name = deparse(substitute(df))` shows where the table name comes from.

We can see what that turns into:

```
res <- list("iris" = iris, "cars" = cars)
tmp = lapply(res, function(x) print(deparse(substitute(x))))
#> [1] "X[[i]]"
#> [1] "X[[i]]"
```

The `name` for the table in the `SQLite` source is `X[[i]]`; once the first line has been executed, the table already exists.

We can resolve by either using an explicit `for` loop and passing the name secondarily, or by using `lapply` on an index number.

For instance:

```
res <- list("iris" = iris, "cars" = cars)
my_db <- dplyr::src_sqlite(paste0(tempdir(), "/foobar.sqlite3"),
                           create = TRUE)
lapply(seq_along(res), function(i, l){dplyr::copy_to(my_db, l[[i]], names(l)[[i]])}, l = res)
my_db %>% tbl("iris") %>% head

#> Source:   query [?? x 5]
#> Database: sqlite 3.8.6 
#> 
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>   <chr>
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

my_db %>% tbl("cars") %>% head

#> Source:   query [?? x 2]
#> Database: sqlite 3.8.6 
#> 
#>   speed  dist
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     2
#> 2     4    10
#> 3     7     4
#> 4     7    22
#> 5     8    16
#> 6     9    10
```

Comment: I found this formatting easier to read: `lapply(seq_along(res), function(i, dt = res) dplyr::copy_to(my_db, dt[[i]], names(dt)[[i]]))`

Answer (score 0):

If someone prefers a `{purrr}` option:

```
imap(res, ~dplyr::copy_to(dest = my_db, 
                            df = .x,
                            name = .y,
                            overwrite = TRUE))
```

or

```
imap(res, ~dbWriteTable(conn = my_db, .y,
                                        value = .x,
                                       overwrite = TRUE))
```